# Natbib with citep extending to sentence before reference

Tags: citing, natbib

I am using natbib for references and citations. There are few instances where I have to use a reference within brackets and for that I use citep command.

For example, for a sentence like:

*Following the previous literature (XYZ, 2020; ABC, 2019)*

So in tex file, I write:

```
Following the previous literature \citep(XYZ,ABC)
```

The issue is that using citep links the whole sentence instead of (XYZ, 2020; ABC, 2019).

How to overcome this?

Comment: Do you have better luck if you replace `\citep(XYZ,ABC)` with `\citep{XYZ,ABC}`?